# "totalarray=sum(array) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"?

Tags: python

```
array = []
for i in range(6):
    array.append(input("Enter a number: "))
decision=input("Do you want the total or the average? ")
totalarray=sum(array)
if decision=="total":
    print(totalarray)
elif decision=="average":
        print(totalarray/6)
else:
    print("Invaild option")
```

For this program i am supposed to ask the user to enter 6 numbers which are then stored in an arry. The user should be able to pick to see either the total or the average of these numbers. How do I prevent the TypeError?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: Your array is a list of `str`s. `sum`, by default, tried to add its input to 0, which is `int`. If you want integer addition, you need to convert your `input` to `int(input(...))`. If you want string concat, do `"".join(array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast input values into integer since sum function of python refers to integers not to strings.

array.append(int(input("Enter a number: ")))

Answer (score 0):

> How do I prevent the TypeError?

In Python 3, `input` returns the user's input as a string (always). If you want to use it as something other than a string you need to perform that conversion yourself based on what "number" you expect (e.g. integer, float, decimal, ...)